# How to thicken a pipe?

Tags: modeling

I've got this doorhandle from the picture below and i was wondering if there is an easy way to make it thicker? not bigger, only the diameter needs to be thicker.

[image: Pipe which need to be thicker]

Comment: try Alt S (shrink/fatten)?

Comment: yes thats it, didn't know about Alt S, thank you.
Can you make it an answer, that i can mark the post as solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (*Shrink/Fatten*)